# Rails paperclip same id for different filefields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, helper

I want to use the paperclip gem to upload a thumbnail for of my blog stories.

I added the paperclip gem, added the following line to the `Post` model

```
    has_attached_file :thumb, styles: {thumb: "453x300>" }
```

I also made a migration (and migrated it)

```
rails g paperclip post thumb
```

Now In my index page, I want add a button next to every story to upload a thumbnail to this story. So I add for every post in the index this form helper.

```
 <%= form_for post, html: { multipart: true  } do |f| %> 
        <%= f.file_field :thumb, as: :file %> 
        <%= f.submit %> 
 <% end %>
```

Now everything works well, but I noticed that all the file_fields (the button that says "choose file", have the same `id`, namely #post_thumb

As I said, all works fine, but I don't think it's best practice (or wise) to have so many elements in your page with the same id. Can anyone help me figure out what I might have done wrong, or how I should do it?l
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `id` of the file uploader.

```
 <%= f.file_field :thumb, as: :file, id:"some-unique-id" %>
```